# Ignore pin input while code executes

Tags: gpio, python

I'm fairly certain this is Raspberry Pi 101, but I've googled it and get results that aren't relevant.

I want to run script after a button press, but I want to disable further button presses until the code has finished running.

so something along the lines of

```
while True:
 Run = GPIO.input(XX)
 if Run == False: /counter intuitive I know
       XXXXXXX disable input from XX
       -other code
       -other code
       XXXXXXXX enable input from XX
```

Comment: Well depending on what's hanging off it you might be able to set the pin to an output suring the input handler.  But unless you have event-driven code/an interrupt triggered off the pin (and it doesn't look like you do), just not testing the pin while executing the script should be enough.

Comment: Let me try that.

Comment: Yup, that works. Thanks! on a completely different note, how do I mark that as an answer on here?

Comment: See: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Of course, someone would have to actually post the solution as an answer first. :P

Comment: Convert comment to answer? :)

Comment: I dont seem to have that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the Input to an Output while the code executed works.